# Can overstay Stamp in one country will it affect for entering US country?

Tags: usa, passports, overstaying, south-africa

I have overstayed stamp in South Africa country... I have US visa so I have to enter US country ... So will it be a problem to enter US country having a overstayed stamp? Please do reply soon

Comment: This is a site entirely run by volunteers. Requests of the *please reply soon* type are unnecessary - people will reply if they can and want. Please [edit] it out (and at the same time put the visa type in, as *Traveller* requested).

Comment: @Likitha What type of US visa do you have?

Comment: Assuming you got the visa AFTER the overstay - than you should be good. If that is not the case, you can always change to a new passport.in extreme cases and assuming your valid visa is in the same passport as the "bad stamp" you could also apply for a new visa ( supply a photocopy of old one ) for the new passport but in my experience when using old passport with visa together with new passport the officers always just check the first ( details ) page .

Answer (score 3):

The bottom line is the USA takes into consideration how you abide by immigration laws in other countries. That’s one reason why the visa application forms ask if you have traveled to other countries.

Nobody can say definitively whether you will have problems entering the USA, they might even not notice it in the passport. However it is never a positive and people have been denied entry for such infractions elsewhere.